# How to extract mixed/partly absent records to a defined order with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following data (it also contains other lines, here is a meaningful extract):

```
group
bb 1
cc 1
dd 1
end
group
dd 2
bb 2
end
group
aa 3
end
```

I don't know the values (like "1", "2", etc.) and have to match by the names (generic "group", "aa", etc.)
I want to get the data filtered and sorted in the following order (with empty tabs when the string is absent):

```
group       bb 1    cc 1    dd 1
group       bb 2            dd 2
group   aa 3
```

I run:

```
awk 'BEGIN {ORS = "\t"}\
/^group/ {print "\n" $0}; \
/^aa/ {AA = $0}; \
/^bb/ {BB = $0}; \
/^cc/ {CC = $0}; \
/^dd/ {DD = $0}; \
/^end/ {print AA; print BB; print CC; print DD}' test.txt
```

and get

```
group       bb 1    cc 1    dd 1
group       bb 2    **cc 1**    dd 2
group   aa 3    **bb 2**    **cc 1**    **dd 2**
```

which is in the right order, but the data is wrong (marked with asterisks). What is the correct way to do this filtering?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- input lines do not start with any white space
- each `^group` has a matching `^end`
- the first line in the file is `^group`
- the last line in the file is `^end`
- there are no lines (to ignore) between `^end` and the next `^group`

Primary issue is that each time `group` is seen we need to clear/reset the other variables otherwise we carryover the values from the previous `group`.

Other (minor) issues:

- `ORS` vs `OFS`
- multiple `print` commands vs a single `print` command
- no need for line continuation characters (`\`)

One idea for an updated `awk` script:

```
awk '
BEGIN    { OFS="\t" }
/^group/ { AA=BB=CC=DD="" ; next }
/^aa/    { AA=$0          ; next }
/^bb/    { BB=$0          ; next }
/^cc/    { CC=$0          ; next }
/^dd/    { DD=$0          ; next }
/^end/   { print "group",AA,BB,CC,DD }
' test.txt
```

**NOTE:** the `; next` clauses are optional and are included as a visual reminder that we don't need to worry about the rest of the script (for the current line)

This generates:

```
group           bb 1    cc 1    dd 1
group           bb 2            dd 2
group   aa 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler `awk` solution to do the same:

```sh
awk '/^group$/{delete m; next} {m[$1]=$0} /^end$/{
 printf "group\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", m["aa"], m["bb"], m["cc"], m["dd"]
}' file

group         bb 1   cc 1   dd 1
group         bb 2          dd 2
group   aa 3
```

Comment: unfortunately, it does not: the result does not keep the tab/string position.

Comment: Yeah I realized mismatch in my output. It is fixed now

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `awk` try following code. Written and tested with shown samples only. Simple explanation would be, setting RS as end\n(optional) and then simply substituting new lines with spaces and printing the line.

```
awk -v RS='end\n?' 'RT{gsub(/\n/,OFS);print}' Input_file
```

***OR*** in case you want to have output as tab delimited then try following:

```
awk -v RS='end\n?' -v OFS="\t" 'RT{gsub(/\n/,OFS);print}' Input_file
```